# Is there a way to log caught exceptions via chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, error-handling, console, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing on the Salesforce platform, which puts me in the situation where I have dependencies on JS developed by Salesforce that is immutable to me.

Unfortunately these components have some interesting behaviors where they handle their own exceptions, and then simply break silently.

I am in need of being able to capture a log for "caught" exceptions, similar to how chrome console can "Pause on caught exceptions", but instead of "Pausing" I need to be able to log the issue.

Is there any mechanism built into chrome console to allow for this? As stated, I cannot add error handling to the components in question myself.